# update table field with another field value if the value if blank in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the table with two columns companyName and accountName.I want to check the the company value is empty and update the field with value accountName in the same row

```
testTable
id companyName accountName
1   a            a1
2                b1         //update with b1 in companyNAme field
3   c            c1
4                d1        //update with  d1 in companyNAme field
```

I want to check if the  companyName field is empty then update with companyName with accountName field value .From the abobe example I want to update id 2 companyName name with value b1 and id 4 companyName name with value d1 in postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple update:

```
UPDATE "testTable" 
SET "companyName" = "accountName"
WHERE "companyName" IS NULL;
```

It would be better to not have capitalization in the column and table names, to avoid requiring those quotation marks.